# Why is \n from an ini file not working?

Tags: c#, .net, escaping

I am just curious about the title.

```
String a = "abc\ndef";
Console.Writeline(a);
```

The output is

```
abc
def
```

Then I stored that value into an ini file and retrieved it from there.

```
ini.iniwritevalue("a", "a", a);
string b = ini.inireadvalue("a", "a");
```

Then I showed it on the console. The result is the following:

```
abc\ndef
```

Why is `\n` not working after I retrieved it from the ini file?

P.S. I have a ini.dll file. Our company is using that dll to read and write ini files.

Comment: How am i supposed to give answer since all 3 answers are correct??

Comment: You can mark as the correct answer the one that helped you the most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interpretation of the \n escape code in your source code is done by the compiler when parsing the source file.

If you just read in a file as "data" at runtime, no such interpretation is necessarily going to occur.

You may need to find or write a function which takes a string containing escape sequences and converts them to binary values (\n usually becomes 0x0a)

Answer (score 3):

This is because `\n` in C# is not just a `\` and an `n`, but an escape sequence with a special meaning. `\n` is considered a single character and is a line ending. You will not get it when you simply read a `\` and an `n` from a file.

Possibly, you read `\\n` from there. `\\` is also an escape sequence which means the `\` character. All you have to do is replace `\\n` with `\n`, and it'll be okay.

```
string s = ... //get the value
s = s.Replace("\\n", "\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the slash when you write the value, like this:

```
abc\\ndef
```